# Entity Framework: how to update wpf datagrid multiple rows at once

Tags: mvvm, entity-framework-5

I'm using MVVM and Entity Framework for LOB application where one of the views contains datagrid, and i can update 1 row at a time. But for large quantity of data it is more practical to have the ability to update mulitple rows at a time.Is this possible with EF?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ViewModels to wrap your business objects (model) then you should have no problem updating the models of multiple row VMs on the fly.

Comment: Yes i'm using ViewModels to wrap my business objects (model)and i have to select the row in the datagrid, make the changes then click update button no problem with this, the point is how could i make changes in many rows and click update button once to submit changes in all modified rows, how can i do that on the fly

Comment: You can start a transaction, make all your changes and then try to submit them all at once right? using EF.

Comment: @atomaras I don't think he's worried about multiple queries, rather he's trying to update the same column for multiple rows of data with one action in the UI.